# Branch or tag before, or else prepare a potential build failure after successful git pull?

Tags: git, undo

Say I have a application that fail building after a successful Git pull (e.g. compilation fails). How can I just 'cancel' the merge and get back to the previous state?

Comment: Is it at all an option not to work directly on the remote branch?  Then you could `pull` from repository, check to see if it builds, and if it does, `rebase` your work on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vonbrand pointed out, you can see the recent reflog entries with:

```
git reflog
```

Once you know approximately how far back, let's say 10 commits, you issue an *interactive* rebase command, like Steven Penny pointed out:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This pulls up an editor.  In it, you can choose to delete commits entirely or perform other actions on each one.  Every line you delete in the editor will be a commit deleted.  The Git comments inline are pretty helpful, but this is important enough to remember that I mentioned it here.  It will look something like this, probably with a mix of good and bad commits:

```
pick 8042b55 Added important file
pick 3459cce Add junk files
pick cb2e26d Adding another change I want to keep
pick b00221f Add stuff I won't want to keep in the file.

# Rebase b0fd283..b00221f onto b0fd283
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

Remember to push your changes up to the server.  'git pull' will fail until you do so.

Here's a semi dangerous command you can use after the rebase succeeds to force push the changes to origin:

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `git rebase` for this job, because a nice list pops up where I can choose the commits to get rid of. Choose how many commits you want to list, then invoke like this

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Sample list

```
pick aa28ba7 Sanity check for RtmpSrv port
pick c26c541 RtmpSrv version option
pick 58d6909 Better URL decoding support
```

Then git will remove commits for any line that you remove.

Comment: Thanks Steven.  Any pointers on resolving the disconnect between the local repository and the upstream (origin) one now?  I've followed your steps and it looks like doing a fast-forward is now necessary since origin is 2 commits ahead. (I used your commands to delete 2 commits from the local git)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `git reflog`, it records changes done to the repository. If you last pull screwed up stuff, you want to go back to `HEAD@{1}`.

Better find out *why* it doesn't build anymore. Maybe upstream isn't careful with dependecies in the Makefiles, and you are trying to combine old objects with freshly compiled ones. Do a full clean, typically `make clobber` or `make distclean` or some such, or even a heavy-handed `git clean`.

In any case, I'd try to give something back for the code you get for free, even if it is only a detailed bug report.